# shell: build variable with multiple paths and commands

Tags: shell

Is there a way to build a varible like this:

```
var="-i \"/path to/file 1.mp4\" -i \"/path to/file 2.mp4\""
```

And then use this later in a program:

```
ffmpeg $var
```

I know `\"` doesn't work, and `eval` works in a way, but eval can be ugly.

Is there a solution without eval?

Comment: Does the way you've built the variable in your question not work? It looks fine to me. Also, what shell?  POSIX?  bash?  If you're using a more advanced shell like bash/zsh/ksh/fish, you might get useful results by reading the documentation about Arrays.

Comment: @ghoti This is attempt is not fine. The intention is for `$var` to expand to 4 arguments, but in this example it expands to 8 in a POSIX-compliant shell: `-i`, `"/path`, `to/file`, `1.mp4"`, `-i`, `"/path`, `to/file`, and `2.mp4"`. The embedded quotes are literal characters that do not protect the surrounded whitespace from word-splitting.

Comment: @chepner Right, of course, I should have been more explicit. The expansion works with word splitting as expected using `eval`; my test was to do the assignment as shown, then `eval set -i $var`, then inspect `$1`, `$2`, etc. If you can trust your input not to break things, there's little harm in using `eval`. If the OP's shell supports it, I still think a simple array might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next best thing to do is to build an array. When you put `${var[@]}` somewhere, it will replace it with the complete array contents. If you put `"${var[@]}"` somewhere (with quotes), the elements of the array will be quoted, so elements with spaces will not be split at the whitespace into  multiple elements:

```
#!/bin/bash

function test() {
    for ((i=0; i<$#; i++)) {
        echo "Param $i: ${!i}"
    }
}

var[0]="-i"
var[1]="/a/path"
var[2]="-i"
var[3]="/second/path with space/"

test "${var[@]}"
```

Will output:

```
Param 0: test.sh
Param 1: -i
Param 2: /a/path
Param 3: -i
```

and that is exactly what you require.
I only tried this in bash, other shells may behave differently.

Comment: Thank you Dennis! This is exactly what I need! And the array fits also perfect in my script.

Comment: Nice to see I could help!